# Code Book Background Subtraction - Everything explodes to become white

Tags: opencv, background-subtraction

I am new to the OpenCV background subtraction model that is definte using codebook method.

I was running the sample code [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads194/sourcecode/windows/911138/bgfg_codebook.cpp__.htm) and to see how it works, seems a very great approach. I was trying to segment out a cup. Works fine until the cup gets close to the camera at which point the whole output of the both foreground codebook image and codebook connected component image, both turn completely white.

Why does this happen?

Wajih

Answer (score 2):

can you try turning off automatic exposure/brightness control of your camera? it could be causing illumination changes in the scene and thus being registered as fg.

Comment: Well that is something that I cannot really control :(

Comment: i think most webcams and ipcams allow manual setting. vlc can be used to set if it is a webcam just in case you dont know

Comment: Well let me check if I can. I am using my Dell laptop so not sure if the setting changes are allowed